# How can I get and compare the ColorType from loaded image, using the image crate?

Tags: image, rust

The situation is below:

```
let i = image::load_from_memory( &buffer ).unwrap();
// The problem
if i.[[[how_get_the_ColorType??]]] != image::ColorType::RGB(8) {
    return None;
}
```

How get and compare the `ColorType` of `i`?

---

I have read these docs but I can't understand them well enough:

- https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/trait.Pixel.html
- https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/trait.GenericImage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image::load_from_memory()` returns a `Result` containing a [`DynamicImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/enum.DynamicImage.html) if successful. `DynamicImage` has a [`color()` method](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.color), which is the `ColorType` you are looking for.

So you want:

```
if i.color() != image::ColorType::RGB(8) {
    return None;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.

if i.color() != image::ColorType::RGB( 8 )
{ return None; }